# Translate normal sql query to Criteria query

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I have a normal sql query like :

```
  String sql = "select * from Comm c where " +
        "c.id in (select max(c.id) from Comm c, ReadComm rc where c.createdby=1 or (c.createdby = 1 and rc.userid=5) and c.id=rc.commid group by c.commThread) " +
        "and c.isdelete = false order by c.senton desc";
```

Is it possible to convert such query to criteria ? I googled about it, but did not get such type of example.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are using Hibernate 4+ then it's pretty simple, you can use a `DetachedCriteria` and their respective projections (for max, group and order by).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take a look at DetachedCriteria and [Subqueries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Subqueries.html).

Something like this:

```
// Create subquery
DetachedCriteria sub = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Comm.class, "sub");
sub.createAlias("sub.readComm", "rc");
sub.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("sub.createdby", 1), ...
sub.setProjection(Projections.max("sub.id"));

// Create main query
Criteria.forClass(Comm.class)
   .add(Subqueries.propertyEq("id", sub)) // id property == value of subquery
   .add(Restrictions.eq("isdelete", false))
   .addOrder(Order.desc("senton"))
   .list();
```